# How to sort first two numbers in sublists

Tags: list-manipulation, sorting

Given

```
t7 = t8 = {{3, 5, 1}, {19, 2, 9}, {4, 3, 1}, {19, 0, 8}};
```

I want to `Sort` the first two numbers in each sublist and keep the third number in its position. I can do it by

```
t7[[All, {1, 2}]] = Sort /@ t7[[All, {1, 2}]]
t7
```

or

```
 t8[[All, {1, 2}]] = # & /@ #[[Ordering[#]]] & /@ t8[[All, 1 ;; 2]]
 t8
```

to get

```
{{3, 5, 1}, {2, 19, 9}, {3, 4, 1}, {0, 19, 8}}
```

But there must be more elegant ways to do it. Any idea?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use [`SubsetMap`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SubsetMap) for this:

```
SubsetMap[Sort,{1,2}] /@ {{3,5,1}, {19,2,9}, {4,3,1}, {19,0,8}}
```

> {{3, 5, 1}, {2, 19, 9}, {3, 4, 1}, {0, 19, 8}}

Comment: Thank you! Good function! Didn't know it.

Answer (score 7):

```
Append[Sort@Most@#, Last@#]& /@ t7
```

Or with `Through`:

```
Flatten@Through[{Sort@*Most, Last}@#] & /@ t7
```

Answer (score 5):

Let sf2 stand for sortfirst2,

```
sf2 = # /. {a_, b_, c___} /; a > b -> {b, a, c} &

t7 = {{3, 5, 1}, {19, 2, 9}, {4, 3, 1}, {19, 0, 8}};

sf2 /@ t7

{{3, 5, 1}, {2, 19, 9}, {3, 4, 1}, {0, 19, 8}}
```

Comment: Or `Replace[t7, {a_, b_, c___} /; a > b -> {b, a, c}, 1]` (to act only at level 1) or `t7 /. {a_, b_, c___} /; a > b -> {b, a, c}` (because the condition makes it so that the entire expression doesn't change and it goes to subexpressions).

Answer (score 2):

```
list = {{3, 5, 1}, {19, 2, 9}, {4, 3, 1}, {19, 0, 8}};
```

Using `Comap` (new in 14.0) and `Splice` (new in 13.1)

```
Comap[{Splice @* Sort @* Most, Last}] /@ list
```

{{3, 5, 1}, {2, 19, 9}, {3, 4, 1}, {0, 19, 8}}

Using `Query`

```
Query[All, {Splice @* Sort @* Most, Last}] @ list
```

{{3, 5, 1}, {2, 19, 9}, {3, 4, 1}, {0, 19, 8}}

Answer (score 2):

```
list = {{3, 5, 1}, {19, 2, 9}, {4, 3, 1}, {19, 0, 8}};
```

Using `ReplaceList`:

```
ReplaceList[list, {___, s : {__}, ___} :> {Splice@Sort@Most@s, Last@s}]

(*{{3, 5, 1}, {2, 19, 9}, {3, 4, 1}, {0, 19, 8}}*)
```